# Apply a changeset to a branch when directory has been renamed

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, tfvc

I have made some changes in a branch which involve renaming the sub-dir a project's code files live in, and committed this branch. I was unaware that while I was working on my branch, another developer made changes to one of the source files in this sub-directory and committed this.

When I merged my branch, it didn't detect the other developer's changes and undid them silently, which we only found later. When I try to re-apply their changeset, it just restores the files in their previous location.

I can manually re-apply their changes since it's an isolated case, but is there actually a way I can apply a changeset in this scenario, tell TFS the two directories are equivalent or something?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you can use `tf merge` command from command line with `/recursive` keyword, as since there is no way to specify the old name of the source branch from the UI, but we can from the TF merge command line.